# TCL Tcllib DES wrong parameters?

Tags: parameters, tcl, des

I want to use the DES function from the Tcllib, but it seems I do not handle the
variables in a correct way.

Here is the code:

```
set key DAAE57F813459B3B
set key_b [binary format H* $key]

set data 2D7A99F520D684B4
set data_b [binary format H* $data]

set result [DES::des -dir encrypt -key $key_b -hex $data_b]
```

When using these values I got an error:

```
bad option "-z...": must be one of -chunksize, -dir, -hex, -in, -iv, -key, -mode, -out, -weak
```

It seems that the DES function is interpreting '2D...' as '-z...' and therefore as an option (which is not allowed).

When I exchange the values (key <-> data, data <-> key) I do not get an error.
Also when I use data 1D..., 3D... etc. the function works fine.

I am using Tcllib V1.18 and packages: des, sha1, pki, asn, aes, math::bignum, md5, base64.

Does anybody has an idea how to hand over the variable 'data' to the DES function without interpreting the data as option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the high-level driver code in the `DES::des` command is confused by the data beginning with a `-` (0x2D) byte. That's a reportable bug; please report it.

But you can work around it by using the *low-level* interface in the Tcllib des package:

```
package require des

set key DAAE57F813459B3B
set key_b [binary format H* $key]

set data 2D7A99F520D684B4
set data_b [binary format H* $data]

# The [binary format] below is for the initialisation vector (IV) which should usually be
# 64 zero bits to start with if you're using simple encryption.
set d [DES::Init cbc $key_b [binary format I* {0 0}]]
set encBytes [DES::Encrypt $d $data_b]
DES::Final $d

# We've got the bytes out; let's convert to hex for printing

binary scan $encBytes H* encHex
puts $encHex;    # --> “4cd33892969591b4”
```

Going in the reverse direction is pretty easy too:

```
package require des

set key DAAE57F813459B3B
set key_b [binary format H* $key]

set encHex 4cd33892969591b4
set encBytes [binary format H* $encHex]

set d [DES::Init cbc $key_b [binary format I* {0 0}]]
set decBytes [DES::Decrypt $d $encBytes]
DES::Final $d

binary scan $decBytes H* decHex
puts $decHex;    # --> “2d7a99f520d684b4”
```

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, it's probably a good idea to wrap the core encryption/decryption up in a procedure. Which is not much different to what `DES::des` really is, except that's more generic (and — obviously — buggy)

Answer (score 0):

Using the end-of-switches marker "--" also seemed to fix this bug for me (using des 1.1.0).

```
set result [DES::des -dir encrypt -key $key_b -hex -- $data_b]
puts $result 
 => 4cd33892969591b4
```